# Cannot find logical error in C++ program

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

I am making a timetable generator as a project.

A part of the code seems to have a logical error.

```
void _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int time=4;
    int classes=2;
    int teacher=4;
    const int column=4;     
    const int rows=8;           
    int table[rows][column];
    int final_table[rows][column];
    int cell;
    int temp=time;
    int temp2=classes;
    int temp3=teacher;
    int cell_reset=111;
    int cell_temp;
    int k=0;
    int selector_temp=0;
    int selector_temp2=0;

    cell=111;

    //array initilization loop
    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<rows;j++)
        {
            table[i][j]=-1;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<rows;j++)
        {
            final_table[i][j]=-1;
        }
    }

    //Number generator loop
    for(int i=0;i<rows;)
    {
        while(k<classes)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<column;j++)
            {
                table[i][j]=cell;
                cell++;
            }
            cell=cell_reset+10;
            k++;
            i++;
        }
        k=0;
        cell=cell_reset+100;
        cell_reset=cell;
    }

    //selector loop 
    int counter=0;
    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        counter=0;
        for(int j=0;j<column&&counter<1;j++)
        {
            if(table[i][j]==selector_temp+10)
            {
                table[i][j]=-1;
            }
            if(table[i][j]==selector_temp-10)
            {
                table[i][j]=-1;
            }
            if(table[i][j]!=-1)
            {
                selector_temp=table[i][j];
                final_table[i][j]=table[i][j];
                for(int gg=(j+1);gg<column;gg++)
                {
                    table[i][gg]=-1;
                }
                selector_temp2=selector_temp;
                while(k<time)
                {
                    selector_temp2+=100;
                    for(int ii=0;ii<rows;ii++)
                    {
                        for(int jj=0;jj<column;jj++)
                        {
                            if(table[ii][jj]==selector_temp2)
                            {
                                table[ii][jj]=-1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    k++;
                }
                k=0;
                counter++;
            }

        }
    }

//display loop
        for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
        {
        for(int j=0;j<column;j++)
        {
            cout<<final_table[i][j];
            cout<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
        }
}//end of main bracket
```

This code generates exactly what I want.

But when I try to run this code the compiler gives me error that

> Stack around the variable table is corrupt.

I choose to ignore this error and then the program gives me the correct result.

I have tried to find the source of this error but I cannot on the top of that I am getting correct results so if it cannot be found how can I disable the prompt that the compiler gives me.

Comment: `void _tmain()` is not valid standard C++.

Comment: What *exactly* does the error say? And if it is an error, how can you ignore it? Is it a warning, instead? Does it occur when you *compile* the code or when you *run* it? And which compiler are you using?

Comment: Standard C++ or not, `void _tmain()` is wrong. If you're using Microsoft's `_tmain()`, it's prototyped as returning an `int`.

Comment: What did you try to debug it?  If I could not step through with a debugger, I would probably start by printing out the index of every loop during the run.

Comment: your code can be written clearer to make it easier to read, but the answer of "Douglas Leeder" is hte solution of one error. What is the text of the error given by the compiler.

Answer (score 5):

The two initialisation loops are wrong - the inner loop should have `j<column`